# Need steps and path to clone source code of eclipse 2018-09

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-2018-09

I want to compile equinox version inside eclipse code, for reason: I want to clone source code for Eclipse version 2018-09 project.
Need steps/path to clone 2018-09 project (https://wiki.eclipse.org/Category:SimRel-2018-09)
Help will highly be appreciated.

Comment: Eclipse source code is [here](https://git.eclipse.org/c/)

Comment: The Eclipse Installer in the advanced mode could be helpful for that: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Oomph/article.html

Comment: ahh.. you mean to clone whole eclipse as source code :P

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got the Wiki link to clone and build complete Eclipse platform (aggregator).
This wiki also tells which branch you need to check out based on ur requirement https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Platform_SDK_Provisioning